# Twilio Client React - BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio

I tried installing the Twilio Client package for an integration in my project and I'm getting this error:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
```

When importing the Device object:

```
import { Device } from 'twilio-client';
```

I searched the error and tried a bunch of things but nothing works. Is this a Twilio bug or something I can fix?

**EDIT: I tried using the new version because apparently this was deprecated, the new version is `@twilio/voice-sdk` but I'm getting the same error.**

Answer (score 0):

Idk if this will work for everyone but doing `npm i util` fixed it.